# Where is the BCD located in windows vista/7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, boot

I'm trying to find where the BCD (Boot Configuration Data) store is actually stored in windows vista/7. This is the information which in previous versions was stored in the boot.ini file (usually located in C:).

I'm able to access the BCD through the command line tool bcdedit.exe, however I don't know where it reading the information from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BCD00000000
But I double you can consume it directly, it seems encoded.
Thanks